# Multiple-choice responses in Dialogflow CX

Tags: google-cloud-platform, chatbot, dialogflow-cx

I'm building a chatbot with Dialogflow CX. In some steps of the process I need the users to choose between some flows (create user, modify data, etc). How should I go about presenting the user with this options, as in buttons? Thanks!

I have surfed the web for info on this and found [custom payloads](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/fulfillment#payload) might help.